# Can I access missed calls from my iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I want to access the log of missed calls in my iPhone app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible from within a legitimate iPhone app.  It may be possible on a jailbroken device, but there is no API call to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not support to implement this type of functionality. It has done only on jailbroken devices.